# Why UI isn't instantiate when I create a new object that has Canvas as a child component?

Tags: unity

I have this object called Treant and I instantiated him from another Object called spawn. The spawn only instantiates a new Treant every second or not.

My problem is that the Treant has a Health bar but that same health bar isn't instantiated in the other Treant that I clone. The health bar will only appear in the next Treant the is created after I destroy the one that has the Health bar.

How can I made all Treants have the Health Bar on top of them?

This is my Spawn class:

```
 // Start is called before the first frame update
public Component Enemies;
public Component Target;
private float lastSpawn = 5;
private float waited = 0f;
private int spawnPerWave = 1;
private int spawned = 0;
private List<int> fibonacci = new List<int>
{
    1, 1
};


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    CreateNewWave();
    Spawn();    
}

private void Spawn()
{
    waited += Time.deltaTime;

    if (lastSpawn < waited && spawned < spawnPerWave)
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawned");
        waited = 0;
        spawned += 1;
        var enemy = Instantiate(Enemies);
        enemy.GetComponent<EnemyAI>().target = Target;
    }
}

private void CreateNewWave()
{
    if(spawned == spawnPerWave && fibonacci.Count < 4)
    {
        spawned = 0;
        spawnPerWave = fibonacci[fibonacci.Count - 1] + fibonacci[fibonacci.Count - 2];
        fibonacci.Add(spawnPerWave);
    }
}
```

[image: Objects following around my player object, but one of them does not have a health bar instantiated]

The Canvas config:

[image: Canvas configuration]

The Slider config:

[image]

The code from FollowTransform:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowTransform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform m_objectToFollow;
    private RectTransform m_rect;

    void Start()
    {
        m_rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        this.m_rect.anchoredPosition = CanvasManager.Instance.WorldToCanvasPoint(m_objectToFollow.position);
    }
}
```

Canvas Manager Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CanvasManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rect m_canvasRect;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private static CanvasManager canvasManager;
    public static CanvasManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return canvasManager;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if(canvasManager != null && canvasManager != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            canvasManager = this;
        }

        m_canvasRect = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;
    }

    public Vector2 WorldToCanvasPoint(Vector3 a_position)
    {

        Vector2 viewport = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(a_position);
        return Vector2.right * (viewport.x - 0.5f) * m_canvasRect.width + Vector2.up * (viewport.y - 0.5f) * m_canvasRect.height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured the canvas inside the treant, and any positioning scripts you might be using?

Comment: @DMGregory just added to the question the configs from Canvas, Slider and the script that I'm using to set the position to the Slider. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the Canvas Manager Script. It has a Singleton to the canvas, so the canvas isn't been instantiated every time that a Treant is created.

To solve this, just remove the singleton. I got some help from [Sid Makes Game](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJYcHqXOF9k1mRRc73w-IEw)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CanvasManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rect m_canvasRect;
    public static CanvasManager Instance { get; private set; }

    void Start()
    {
        Instance = this;        
        m_canvasRect = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;
    }

    public Vector2 WorldToCanvasPoint(Vector3 a_position)
    {

        Vector2 viewport = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(a_position);
        return Vector2.right * (viewport.x - 0.5f) * m_canvasRect.width + Vector2.up * (viewport.y - 0.5f) * m_canvasRect.height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the Treant prefab has the canvas on it and that the values on it are correct.

If it's not the prefab then maybe Canvas has a singleton script on it that destroys any new instances of itself.

You can then do a sanity check. Get and print all the components on the Treant before instantiating (in Start()) and then after. You can do it like this

```cs
foreach(var component in Enemies.GetComponents<Component>())
{
    Debug.Log(component.name)
}
```

---

Also maybe instead of

```cs
 public Component Enemies;
```

use

```cs
public GameObject Enemies;
```

That's not the problem, but when given a GameObject `Component` references the first component it finds on it i.e. Transform. So when you're doing `enemy.GetComponent<EnemyAI>()` it translates to `enemy.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyAI>()` so it's pointless to use `Component` instead of `GameObject`

Comment: Thank you for the help, but It didn't solved =/. Just updated the question to have more info. The GameObject tip was new for me. Thanks